# "The University of X", "University of X", or "X University"? Is there any rule?

Tags: meaning

I cannot understand that why the name of some universities starts with "The University of....", in some cases we see "University of...", and finally we see ".... University"!!!! Some examples are as follows:

1. University of Oxford
2. McGill University
3. The University of
   Manchester

QUESTION: Is there any general rule on using the above three options? Or it has been chosen by chance? At first, it seems to me that when we are talking about a university bearing the name of a city or province, we should use "The". But this is not the case in general. For example we have "University of Alberta", without "The". **What is going on here**?

Comment: Every university has its own traditions; just like proper names everywhere. It's _The University of Michigan, Michigan State University,_ and _The Ohio State University,_ for instance. They have to be learned individually.

Comment: Rutgers tops them all as "Rutgers, The State University of New Jersey."